# The array that I created has unexpected size

Tags: c

I tried to create a temp with the size of i+1, but I found out no matter what the value of i or size is, my code will always create a string with the size of 6. How could this possibly happen?

```
void addWord(char* word, trie* root) {
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
    OBJTYPE v = word[i];
    if(root->children[(int)v] == NULL) {
        trie* node = constructor(root);
        node->value = v;
        int size = i+1;
        char temp[size];
        printf("The value of i is : %d\n", i);
        printf("The value of size is : %d\n", size);
        printf("The copy has the size of: %d\n", strlen(temp));
        strncpy(temp, word, i + 1);
        printf("Now the size of the copy is: %d\n", strlen(temp));
        node->partWord = temp;
        root->children[(int)v] = node;
        root = node;
        printf("The node has value: %c\n", root->value);
        printf("The node stored word has size of : %d\n", strlen(root->partWord));
        printf("The node has stored word: %s\n", root->partWord);
    } else {
        root = root->children[(int)v];
    }
}
trie* end = constructor(root);
end->value = '&';
char temp[strlen(word)];
strcpy(temp, word);
end->partWord = temp;
root->children[SIZE + 1] = end;
}
```

[Here is the debugging message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cdTs.png)

Comment: Strncpy does not always create valid strings.

Comment: Hint for future: use a debugger. It will help you a lot with this kind of issue. Also, it's a really great tools to learn a language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen` checks for the first occurence of `\0`. When you call `strlen` with an uninitialized array, like you do here:

```
    char temp[size];
    printf("The value of i is : %d\n", i);
    printf("The value of size is : %d\n", size);
    printf("The copy has the size of: %d\n", strlen(temp));
```

the content of the array is random, and your program has undefined behavior because you're not allowed to use uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` just counts non-zero bytes starting from the argument pointer. You don't seem to zero your `temp` array anywhere.